# Read another app's preferences plist, or share some prefs?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, plist, nsuserdefaults

I'd like to share a preference between two apps (a game and its editor). How can I best accomplish this? I thought the game could explicitly read from the editor's preferences plist, but I'm not sure what the cleanest way to achieve this is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` maintains a list of domains to search. By default it just looks at your application's preferences file, but you can have it search other places.

You can do something like this:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] init];
[defaults addSuiteNamed:@"com.example.game.shared-prefs"];
```

To share preferences between apps.

Answer (score 2):

Just drop down to CFPreferences APIs for the expert parameters. `NSUserDefaults`' idea of preferences is for an app, but CFPreferences allow you to defines hosts, suites, and so on for the type of multi-app preferences you want.